# Extract input iterator from std::copy and std::copy_n

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I trying to implement an unserialization method that take an input iterator and perform a series of chunk reads (using `std::copy` and `std::copy_n`). Something like this (just an example):

```
template <class InputIt>
InputIt unserialize(InputIt it)
{
  std::copy_n(it, sizeof(header_type), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&header));
  std::copy_n(it, header.payload_size, std::back_inserter(payload));
  it = optional.unserialize(it);
  return it;
}
```

How do I advance input iterator in this case so each following call to `std::copy_n` continue read from it and I can finally return it?

I want to be generic to iterator categories (especially RandomAccessIterator and InputIterator) for performance reasons and hope it is possible to use `std::copy` methods without need to rewrite these. Stuff like bound checking and such will be done by iterator adapter or checked before unserialization call if size is known.

What do not work nor acceptable:

1. Using `std::copy_n<InputIt&>(it, ...)` may work for some categories but not for all and it's too unreliable.
2. Using `std::advance` after each call leads to rereading same block again for some iterators. Not preferable and may be impossible for some sources.

**UPDATE** Making iterator reference adapter doesn't help as *random access iterator* version of `copy_n` return pointer to **past** the last element copied while *input iterator* version return pointer to the last element copied. So I guess own version of `copy_n` works best with additional iterator adapter for bound checking.

Comment: All I can suggest is to reimplement your own `copy_n` function that takes a reference to the iterator, but that's not really desirable - especially given how much work has gone into standard library implementations to optimize their performance.

Comment: *"Using std::advance after each call leads to rereading same block again for some iterators."* - can you describe exactly what you mean here?  Perhaps give an example.

Comment: Are you sure `std::copy_n<InputIt&>` is not guaranteed to work?

Comment: A simple test using `const char*` as iterator not working with `std::copy_n<InputIt&>` but works with possible implementation from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n).

Comment: @JohnZwinck Example is `std::istream_iterator`. [Documentatation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) says "The actual read operation is performed when the iterator is incremented, not when it is dereferenced.".

Comment: @TobySpeight I can't agree more about how much hard work has gone into std library. Also all compiler optimizations that has been done to this code. I was afraid of this answer and I guess I will go for it but I really hope there will be other suggestions too.

Comment: It is unfortunate that Stepanov didn't follow his own philosophy, by not returning both the output and input iterator of the `copy_n` algorithm. http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/stl/copy_n.html . Probably, returning a pair was controversial at the time as not many functions return a pair, and there was probably some apparent fixation to make `copy_n` and `copy` return the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

For [random access iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) this form can be used - and it is fine:

```
template <class InputIt, class N, class OutputIt>
InputIt copy_n_advance_input(InputIt it, N dist, OutputIt outIt)
{
    std::copy_n(it, dist, outIt);
    return std::next(it, dist);
}
```

Unfortunately - problems are when we want to deal with one pass input iterator - like here (got 'd' - not 'c'):

```
std::string s = "abcd";
std::istringstream ss{s};
auto e = copy_n_advance_input(std::istream_iterator<char>(ss), 
                             2, 
                             std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ","));
std::cout << "\n" << *e << "\n";
```

So it seems it is needed, as usual in STL, two forms:

```
template <class InputIt, class N, class OutputIt>
InputIt copy_n_advance_input_impl(InputIt it, N dist, OutputIt outIt,
                                  std::input_iterator_tag)
{
    while (dist-- > 0)
    {
        *outIt = *it;
        ++outIt;
        ++it;
    }
    return it;
}

template <class InputIt, class N, class OutputIt>
InputIt copy_n_advance_input_impl(InputIt it, N dist, OutputIt outIt, 
                                  std::random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    std::copy_n(it, dist, outIt);
    return std::next(it, dist);
}

template <class InputIt, class N, class OutputIt>
InputIt copy_n_advance_input(InputIt it, N dist, OutputIt outIt)
{
    return copy_n_advance_input_impl(it, dist, outIt, typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::iterator_category {});
}
```

Note, the proposed version for `std::input_iterator_tag` is not as efficient as in STL (at least for gcc) - it does extra iteration for input - this iteration is not necessary to perform copy - but it is needed to return beginning of "after copy" range (stl_algo.h):

```
754   template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Size, typename _OutputIterator>
755     _OutputIterator
756     __copy_n(_InputIterator __first, _Size __n,
757          _OutputIterator __result, input_iterator_tag)
758     {
759       if (__n > 0)
760     {
761       while (true)
762         {
763           *__result = *__first;
764           ++__result;
765           if (--__n > 0)
766         ++__first;
767           else
768         break;
769         }
770     }
771       return __result;
772     }
```

Last note - it is wiser to use, for random-access-iterators (like std::vector::iterator) the version that just calls std algorithms - because they can be even more optimized - e.g. for contiguous memory iterator over POD types - that can be just memcpy'ied. Or some specialization for `std::vector<bool>` or `std::deque<T>` exist, that uses their internal structure to perform copy in most efficient way.

Comment: This solution is kind of natural. And it exactly there I end up before asking the question (I should mention it, sorry). And maybe it is the best one, but as mentioned in question I like to avoid to rewrite these functions if there other solutions to this. Still, thank you for sharing, maybe it helps others.

Comment: I was thinking about some kind of new iterator wrapper that keep track of incrementation of original iterator- but it failed just because of that optimal implementation of `__copy_n` for not random iterators - it just returns one less value. And it is very complicated - if you like I can share it - but I really doubt in its usefullness

Comment: No Piotr, that's fine, thank you! It is something I will try (just to compare to this solution) but it is simple to write one.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an **iterator adapter** that always works through a *reference* to the supplied iterator.  Here's the basic skeleton of such an adapter:

```
#include <iterator>

template<typename InputIterator>
struct IteratorReference
{
    InputIterator& it;

    IteratorReference(InputIterator& it)
        : it(it)
    {}
    // {copy, move, destructor} == default

    // iterator methods (TODO: add the rest)
    IteratorReference& operator++()
    { ++it; return this; }

    typename InputIterator::reference operator*()
    { return *it; }

    // Convert back to original iterator
    operator InputIterator() const
    { return it; }
};


template<typename InputIterator>
IteratorReference<InputIterator> make_iterator_reference(InputIterator it)
{
    return it;
}
```

To use it, simply create and use a wrapper in place of the original iterator:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Header
{
    std::size_t payload_size;
};

template <class InputIt>
InputIt unserialize(InputIt it, Header& header, std::vector<char>& payload)
{
    auto i_ref = make_iterator_reference(it);
    std::copy_n(i_ref, sizeof header, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&header));
    std::copy_n(i_ref, header.payload_size, std::back_inserter(payload));
    i_ref = optional.unserialize(i_ref);
    return i_ref;
}
```

Comment: try with `std::forward_list` - for not random_access_iterators - it might now work - I've tried similar solution - see comments under my answer...

Comment: I hadn't seen your comment, @PiotrNycz.  I confess I haven't run this code - only compiled it.  If the question had posted a full example, I'd have been able to experiment with it and actually test what I answer with.

Comment: As I mentioned in UPDATE part of the question using iterator reference adapter is not good idea as random access type and input type will advance iterator differently.

Comment: @pechkin, could this answer be adapted a little, to get where you want to be?  We'd need to keep track of whether the underlying iterator has been dereferenced since last incremented (would we need another layer of wrapping for this?).  It might get too complicated, but perhaps worth investigating.  If there's a real need, you might want to make a Standard Library enhancement proposal for algorithms that accept input iterators by reference (or ones that return a pair).

Comment: @TobySpeight, I guess I'm looking for a "simple trick" people used to solve this problem, but maybe there aren't any. To continue with my project I used my version of `std::copy_n` for now, but I agree, this problem must get an attention of standard library committee.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but... 
Recently I've run into similar issue, and I feel pretty sad when I see there isn't any good solution for this problem...
Nevertheless, I've tried to write an iterator wrapper like what [Toby Speight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850040/toby-speight/) said, and I've extended it a bit.
This wrapper is only used for [`InputIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator), because other kind of iterators supported by [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) are multipass iterators, and it's possible to directly use `std::next` and `std::advance` on them instead of using this wrapper.

```
template<typename Iterator>
struct Wrapper {
    using traits = std::iterator_traits<Iterator>;
    using difference_type = typename Traits::difference_type;
    using reference = typename Traits::reference;
    //...

    reference operator*() const { return *(*(this->current)); }

    //need implement operator++(int) too, in the similar way
    Wrapper& operator++() { 
        if(this->indicator != 0) {
            ++(*(this->current));
            --this->indicator;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    //need to implement operator!= too, in the similar way
    bool operator==(const Wrapper& other) const { 
        return *(this->current) == *(other.current) or this->indicator == other.indicator;
    }

    Iterator* current;
    difference_type indicator;
};

template<typename Iterator>
struct Range {
    using category = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category;
    //...
    using difference_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type;

    constexpr bool isForwardOrAbove() { 
        return std::is_base_of_v<std::forward_iterator_tag, category>;
    }

    using iterator = std::conditional_t<isForwardOrAbove(), Iterator, Wrapper<Iterator>>;

    std::pair<iterator, iterator> splitSubRange(difference_type n) {
        if constexpr (isForwardOrAbove()) {
            //forward iterators are multi-pass iterators, so using std::advance on one iterator will not invalidate its copies
            auto oldBegin = this->begin;
            std::advance(this->begin, n);
            return {oldBegin, std::next(oldBegin, n)};
        }
        else {
            //non-forward-iterator
            return {{&(this->begin), n}, {&(this->end), 0}};
        }
    }

    Iterator begin;
    Iterator end;
}
```

To use them, firstly you need a `Range` object which holds iterators, and use the `splitSubRange` method to obtain plain iterators, or, if they are only `InputIterator`s, iterator wrappers.

```
template<typename InputIterator>
InputIterator unserialize(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end) {
    auto range = Range<InputIterator>{begin, end};
    auto [begin, end] = range.splitSubRange(sizeof(header_type));
    //before having "used" the iterator obtained from range, you shouldn't use range again.
    std::copy(begin, end, header.begin());
    //after having "used" the iterator, you can use the range object to obtain the next sub-range
    auto [begin2, dummy] = range.splitSubRange(sizeof(header_type_2));
    std::copy_n(begin2, sizeof(header_type_2), header2.begin());
    ...
    return range.begin;
}
```